# Как адаптировать слайдер под экран телефона?

Tags: bootstrap, интерфейс, карусель

Каждый раз при верстке слайдеров по пути от больших экранов к телефонам возникает вопрос, как правильно поступить со слайдером. Обычно на нем важный для заказчика текст, несущий основную информацию, но при уменьшении размера экрана текст перестает помещаться на слайдере.

Расскажите, как правильно поступать в этой ситуации, и обоснуйте свою точку зрения. Подойти нужно с философии `Bootstrap`.

Answer (score 3):

Цель слайдера — привлечь внимание и подтолкнуть к нужному действию. Для этого у него целый арсенал: фотографии, заголовки, текст, кнопки и удобная навигация.

Слайдер увеличивает полезное пространство, добавляя экрану горизонтальную «бесконечность». Но на телефоне слайдер перестаёт справляться с задачей:

1. Фотографии уменьшаются настолько, что слова перестают помещаться и навигация загораживает половину картинки. Слайдер превращается в кучу-малу и выглядит неряшливо.
2. Узкую и длинную страницу читают по вертикали, а слайдер переключается поперёк. Чтобы им воспользоваться, приходится вовремя остановиться и перейти на перпендикулярную «тропинку». Это замедляет и затрудняет чтение.
3. Читатель движется по странице, используя «смахивающие» жесты, а слайдер Бутстрапа понимает только нажатия на край экрана.

Поэтому предлагаю на узком экране превращать слайдер в колонку фотографий с пояснениями. Слайды займут больше места, но их станет легче пролистывать, потому что они расположатся в русле чтения.

А для коллекции фотографий подойдёт [фоторама](http://fotorama.io/). Она откликается на привычные «смахивающие» жесты. И посмотрите [совет Артёма Горбунова о слайдерах](http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20130422/).

---

### Превращаем карусель Бутстрапа в колонку фотографий

1. Ставим карусель на паузу, чтобы возобновить с того же слайда, если понадобится.
2. Выстраиваем фотографии в колонку.
3. Перемещаем заголовки и текст под фотографии.

При желании можно уменьшить границу перехода с `767px` до `480px`.

Для 4го Бутстрапа: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/ExxKXZb
Для 3го Бутстрапа: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/rLwAWp

```js
/* 1. */
var isCarouselPaused = false;

$( window ).on( 'load resize', function() {
  if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 767 ) {
    if ( !isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('pause');
      isCarouselPaused = true;
    }
  } else {
    if ( isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('cycle');
      isCarouselPaused = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* 2. */
  .carousel .item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  .carousel-control, 
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* 3. */
  .carousel-caption {
    color: black;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  
  /* Decorations */  
  .carousel-caption h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
}

/* Make the images wide and responsive. */
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Decorations */  
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    
      <h1>Превращаем карусель в колонку фотографий</h1>
      
      <p>На узком экране карусель встаёт на паузу, а фотографии и пояснения к ним выстраиваются в колонку.</p>
      
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Первый заголовок</h3>
              <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Второй заголовок</h3>
              <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Третий заголовок</h3>
              <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```